# Automatically run java applications with trusted certificates

Tags: java, security, certificate

I know there is a way to inject trusted certificates into the java runtime [like this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html), but when a user starts an application using this certificate, he still gets a window much like this

[image: The application's digital signature has been verified. Do you want to run the application?]

When accepting, the certificate is visible in the java control panel.

How can I get the certificate in there without the user needing to accept that warning? I want him to run the application without any obstacles when doing so, meaning the certificate is already trusted AND the application can be run immediately.

Comment: Uhm ... that dialog is a security mechanism. Unless you have a (traditional, native-code) Install-Step with elevated privileges, you *should not* be able to skip it.

Comment: Put differently: if this were possible, then any malware could do it as well.

Comment: "meaning the certificate is already trusted". So, somehow the certificate needs to be placed in the trust store of the machine right? It can't be done automagically/stealthily as the OS won't allow it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Problem is, we distribute this software to many clients which may not understand what to do with such a warning, meaning many many support requests and confused clients... So we figured that maybe we could prevent those messages. I also found this: http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/18875.html - maybe it can be done with that?

Comment: @Arham I don't need stealth or automatics, I just need a way of doing something that we can do BEFORE we grant the users access to the system where this application is hosted, so they don't see the message.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: what you can do is provide a traditional native installer. It doesn't ask any less questions (and on Windows requires answering a similarly scary permission question), but the format is well known and users know how to use those.

Comment: @FlorianPeschka ultimately installing of the certificate requires human intervention, either they do by clicking on the certificate concerned, or you do by some installer as Joachim pointed out or your application does it by throwing the dialog box.

Comment: Well, the application is already installled/deployed. The users will just be granted access to their systems. When they start the application, we want them to immediately be able to start working

Comment: @FlorianPeschka: this looks like it's deployed using JNLP/WebStart. That's *not* equivalent to a native installer **exactly** because it requires the user to verify that letting the application access everything is required (because otherwise it would be too easy to trick the user into runing anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all the guys in the comments, it is now apparent to me, that this is not possible through automation or configuration. The user **has** to accept the warning, as it's a vital security feature of the operating system and Java.